# In MVC3, how to set a nullable property of a Model in vb.Net?

Tags: vb.net, properties, c#-to-vb.net

In MVC3 with C#, a nullable Model's property is defined as

```
public int? MyProperty { get; set; }
```

However how can I translate it in vb.Net language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public property MyProperty As Nullable(Of Integer)
```

Answer (score 3):

`Public Property MyProperty As Integer?`

Answer (score 0):

To expand on this there are 3 accepted ways:

```
Dim ridesBusToWork1? As Boolean
Dim ridesBusToWork2 As Boolean?
Dim ridesBusToWork3 As Nullable(Of Boolean)
```

More information here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/nullable-value-types